# How to count the 0`s of a string inside a neste list with python through a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, counting

I want to return the maximum count of zeros in a nested list such as the following one

```
   lista = [['0000', '', ''], ['', '', '000', ''], ['000', '0', ''], ['', '', '00', '', '']]
```

for that list it should return `[4, 3, 3, 2]`

I have the following code which is giving me a wrong answer: `[0, 0, 1, 0]`

```
print([n.count("0") for n in filas])
```

**I would like it to be answered using list comprehension**

Comment: you are counting how many "0" there are in the sublist and not in the sublist item, you need to have another iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  Try:

```
print([max(n.count("0") for n in sublist) for sublist in lista])
# Output: [4, 3, 3, 2]
```